# How to find linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How come one guess that a certain linear transformation is defined in a certain vector space??
  I have come across some like problems. For e.g:

$T:\mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $T(x,y,z)=(x,z)$

$T:\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $T(x y)=(y,x)$

$T:\mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $T(x,y,z)=(x,y-1,z)$

Are these linear transformations??

Comment: If it doesn't take $0$ to $0$, it's definitely not linear. Beyond that, just try and show that it's linear: that $T(\lambda x) = \lambda T(x)$ and $T(x+y) = T(x) + T(y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should see if it is tru or not that we always have

- $T(v+w)=T(v)+T(w)$;
- $T(\lambda v)=\lambda T(v)$.

You can check that that's a fact for the forst two of your maps. The third one is not linear because, for instance,$$T\bigl(0.(0,1,0)\bigr)=(0,-1,0)\text{ and }0.T(0,1,0)=(0,0,0).$$

Comment: Carlos Santos.Could you be more specific about the 3. I mean if u could provide more examples for the 3.

Comment: @demon For instance $T\bigl(2.(1,1,1)\bigr)\neq2.T(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Carlos Santos Got it. Thanks for ur time.

Comment: @demon I'm glad I could help.